# insert "updated" code in a google doc

Tags: google-docs

At the bottom of a document that we print off, we have an "updated on XXXX" statement. I'd like to be able to have that update automatically.  Is there a way to get an insert code that will insert this type of metadata in a google doc?

Comment: I'm guessing this could be possible with Google App Script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview   I don't know much about it, but if I figure out your problem as I learn, I'll report back.

Comment: That's a great suggestion.  I'll look into it and see if I can find an answer there.  If/when I find the answer I'll post it back here.